# Logout bug in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Currently have a classified site built using Laravel,

```
Laravel Framework 7.20.0
```

This is my routes code

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

this my logout method.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        // Get the current Country
        if (session()->has('country_code')) {
            $countryCode = session('country_code');
        }
        if (session()->has('allowMeFromReferrer')) {
            $allowMeFromReferrer = session('allowMeFromReferrer');
        }
        
        // Remove all session vars
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        
        // Retrieve the current Country
        if (isset($countryCode) && !empty($countryCode)) {
            session(['country_code' => $countryCode]);
        }
        if (isset($allowMeFromReferrer) && !empty($allowMeFromReferrer)) {
            session(['allowMeFromReferrer' => $allowMeFromReferrer]);
        }
        
        $message = t('You have been logged out') . ' ' . t('See you soon');
        flash($message)->success();
        
        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
```

And finally my logout code

```
<a href="{{ lurl(trans('routes.logout')) }}" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="icon-logout hidden-sm"></i> {{ t('log_out') }}
                                </a>
```

When clicking the logout button the header when logged in the page refreshes but no message is displayed and the session doesn't seem to be deleted. Sometimes it does logout but when visiting the user account section it's still logged in. I have tried setting the session to the following settings, Cookie, File and Redis. Currently using Redis for file cache. And have tried a POST method which does not work either.

```
Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9435c3c2879311f3
```

There is no JS errors in my page either and all packages are up to date.

Comment: This is not a bug. You need to expect `logout` from auth controller constructor method.

Answer (score 2):

On your `LoginController` add this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout']]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
public function __construct()
{
    Auth::logout();
}
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.